# React Native Snap Carousel ref getting null on navigating to same page with different params

Tags: react-native, react-native-snap-carousel

[image]

The ref of the React Native Snap Carousel package is becoming null on re rendering the same component with different params.

**What I have tried till now**
Since the package used react native flatlist as its implementation, so i modified my code to the flatlist view and that shows no error

Here are some of the logs of what happens Object - > Navigate - > Null - > Object

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just released [version 3.3.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-snap-carousel) of the plugin today, which should solve your issue.

If you want a deeper understanding of the issue at stake, see [this React Native thread](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10635). Basically, one should apparently avoid using stateless components when rendered inside scroll components. They should be migrated to regular components that extend `Component` or `PureComponent`. See [this comment](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10635#issuecomment-286747320) or [this one](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10635#issuecomment-322091608).

Also, it seems that `Animated` components are sometimes unmounted **before** their parents...